# How to change the font size in a mahapps project?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

So I am trying to change the default font family and the font size in my project. I decided to start with buttons.

I do it like this (I am gonna create a separated file for my style, but now I just want to make it work somehow):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Templates/MyTemplateSelector.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Templates/FullMenu.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
```

and nothing changes. What is wrong?

I guess it's because program can't find "{StaticResource MetroButton}".

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         xmlns:dialogYesNo="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.DialogYesNo"   
         StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewModels.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dialogs.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you just need to use it in App.xaml after declaring metro references:

```
       <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI "/>
        </Style>
```

Button uses TextBox, so button will be changed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of define a style just to set fontfamily/weight you can just define in your resource directly the fontfamily and weight with a key(an example with a font that i use)

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <FontFamily x:Key="FontAwesome">/tuseradm;component/assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome</FontFamily>
</Controls:Flyout.Resources>
```

then in your button just set the font family

```
<Button FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" Content="&#xf14a;" />
```

**EDIT** adding another answer:

by default mahapps override the default wpf style. If you want to modify a style for let's say buttons in all your view you don't need to use based on

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraLight"/>
</Style>
```

**EDIT 2**

At least for me, even if i see the change at design time using the approach exposed in the first edit, at run time the problem persist. So in my opinion, is much better to stick with my first answer. Maybe it could be annoying to set fontfamily and fontweight for each button, but it is the safest way to deal with mahapps styles. The only way to solve this 100% for sure is to find (no clue where) the template of mahapps buttons and modify it

Comment: I don't want to do it for every control - I need to change font family globally.

Comment: @IoannaFerens added another answer. Are you adding the dictionary for styles and controls of mahapps somewhere?

Comment: @IoannaFerens ok have you tried to remove the BasedOn property in your style? Cause a style defined like that works for me usually

Comment: yes, it works - font changes. but I actually want to use MetroButton as a base style, and I don't understand how to do it properly.

Comment: @IoannaFerens it doesn't exist any MetroButton in the dictionary. When you use a MetroWindow, you are telling wpf to override the "classic" buttons look with the ones that mahapps apply, so when you target the Button type, you are already targeting what you call "MetroButton"

Comment: I know I am targeting "MetroButton", i don't know how to change a font in all button with not changind whole style. Because when I do something like
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
            </Style>
Buttons in project stop to be have cute rounded corners like in metro style and etc

Comment: @IoannaFerens ok i should have finally founded a workaround.